How to load multiple JS Files from Webassembly into one script
I have the problem that I can't load multiple JS Files from WebAssembly into my Script and work with them.
I am working with WebAssembly and C right now and when I create a JS and a WASM File with emscripten and add it to my script in HTML it all works.
Here is a little code Example that works:
<script src="hello.js"></script>
<script>
    var js_wrapped_fib = Module.cwrap("fib", "number", ["number"]);
    
    function pressBtn(){
        console.log("The result of fib(5) is:", js_wrapped_fib(5));
    }
    </script>
<button onclick="pressBtn()">Click me!</button>

<button onclick="pressBtn()">Click me!</button>
But when I add another <script src=""></script> a error comes up, for example here is a not working code:
<script src="hello.js"></script>
<script>
    var js_wrapped_fib = Module.cwrap("fib", "number", ["number"]);
    
    function pressBtn(){
        console.log("The result of fib(5) is:", js_wrapped_fib(5));
    }
    </script>
<button onclick="pressBtn()">Click me!</button>

//Here is the new added code

<script src="hello2.js"></script>
<script>
    var js_wrapped_printout = Module.cwrap("printout", "number", ["number"]);

    function pressBtn2(){
        console.log("The clicked button got the number:", js_wrapped_printout(6));
    }
</script>
<button onclick="pressBtn2()">Click for number</button>

Both work seperatly but not together.
This error comes up when I try to execute it in the console:
1st error: hello2.js:539 Aborted(Module.arguments has been replaced by arguments_ (the initial value can be provided on Module, but after startup the value is only looked for on a local variable of that name))
2nd Error: hello2.js:562 Uncaught RuntimeError: Aborted(Module.arguments has been replaced by arguments_ (the initial value can be provided on Module, but after startup the value is only looked for on a local variable of that name))
at abort (hello2.js:557:11)
at Object.get (hello.js:801:9)
at hello2.js:216:11
Can somebody please help to load multiple js/wasm scripts in to one html file?
I tried to write a seperate function which loads scripts outside of the html but same error.
I also tried to load multiple non wasm js files into one html file and it worked perfectly so the problem is with the webassembly.

There doesn't seem to be any C code involved in your problem, right?

the c code is inside the js code it got translated to js that is why there is a c wraped function but the c code it self is not relevant relevant is how to use multiple  in case of webassembly

but no the c code is not the problem only the problem i described above

Then you might think about removing the C language tag.
